# How to move box animation with speed and color

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to create a box animation with speed and color determined by the user.

Here, JavaScript looks at the radio buttons every second to update speed and color.

The panel of speed and color radio buttons and the box should look like this:

[image]

So far, I have the following code:

```js
function radioSet(a, b, c, d = false){   
  document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("form"), {id: a}));
  let e = document.getElementById(a);
  for (let i = 0; i < b; i++){
    document.getElementById(a).append(
    Object.assign(document.createElement("label"), 
    {textContent: (d) ? c[i] + " "  + i : c[i]}), 
    Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), 
    {type: "radio", value: (d) ? c[i] + " "  + i : c[i], name: "assigned"}), )
}
  document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("hr"), {}));
  e.addEventListener("input", () => console.log(a + " change! " + e.assigned.value) )
}


radioSet("speed", 51, Array(51).fill("Speed"), true)
radioSet("color", 3, ["red", "yellow", "blue"])

const box = {
    width: 15, 
    left: 0, 
    end_pos: 80,
    dx: 1, // speed, updated by the speed radio button
    element: null, // the div
    wait: 10, // ms delay, every one second
    event_id: null // event id
};

function animate(){
    if(box.left + box.width <= box.end_pos){ // within window
    box.element.style.left = box.left + "%"; // display

    // update position
    box.left += box.dx;
    box.event_id = setTimeout( animate, box.wait );
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load",
    ()=>{
        box.element = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(box.element);
    });
```

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute; 
}

div{
    width: 40%; /*box width*/
    height: 200px; /*box height*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;  
    background-color: red; /*box color, updated by the color radio buttons*/
}
```

And so far I have created this animation:

[image]

Here, how do I change the speed of the box according to the speed radio button?

Comment: Your question must be 4 separate questions.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was describing the next steps. I updated my post and ask questions accordingly in the future.

Comment: I think that the speed is changed according to the speed radio button

Comment: No, the dx value in box object is 1 for now, need to change this with the speed radio button

Comment: If each input should start at 0, 10, 20, 30..., then the first row will have 11 inputs and the last row (50) will have only one.

Comment: For speed, first first row should be speed 0, meaning the box is not moving. And each next row should have 10 speed, so second row has speed 1 through 10. Next row has speed 11,...,20. So the last row has 41,...,50.

Comment: How come you can’t change the value of box.dx within your event listener function?

Comment: I can, perhaps I can have ```e.addEventListener("input", () => box.dx=i )```. But the thing is the box should move once I click the speed radio button. For example, the box move with speed 1 when the window loads. When I click the speed button, nothing happens. Box should move again once the speed radio button is clicked.